# Application Insights: Script error at unknown

Tags: azure-application-insights

Some of ours client-side exceptions don't contain any details :

```
Script error. at unknown
```

It seams that these errors aren't related to a specific OS or browser:

- Max OS X 10.9 + Chrome 53.0
- Windows 7 + Firefox 49.0
- ...

Is there a way to get more info ?

Comment: msdn thread on topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9859aca5-af2a-47ba-a015-800c200794af/errors-from-azure-insights-script?forum=ApplicationInsights

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I have my answer. Our scripts are behind a CDN :

> Browser exceptions
>   Most browser exceptions are reported.
>
> If your web page includes script files from content delivery networks or other domains, ensure your script tag has the attribute crossorigin="anonymous", and that the server sends CORS headers. This will allow you to get a stack trace and detail for unhandled JavaScript exceptions from these resources.

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-asp-net-exceptions/#browser-exceptions

An other source dealing with the same issue:

http://blog.errorception.com/2012/12/catching-cross-domain-js-errors.html